# Delphi: Set Word ContentControl to temporary programattically

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am inserting a ContentControl into a MS Word document using Delphi 10.4

The content control is inserted, into a bookmark on the template, using the following snippet:

```
procedure TBF.SetPI;
var
  R: WordRange;
  bookmark: OleVariant;
  s: string;
begin
  s:= 'insert text here';
  bookmark := 'textValue';
  R := MF.WordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(bookmark).Range;
  R.Text := s;
  R.HighlightColorIndex := wdYellow;
  MF.WordDoc.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText,R);
end;
```

This successfully creates the ContentControl, however the control is persistant oonce the text has been edited.

Word has an option to mark ContentControls as "temporary" and the VBA for that is

```
Selection.ParentContentControl.Temporary = True
```

Delphi exposes the same as `R.ParentContentControl.Temporary` which requires a `WordBool` value.

Try as I might I cannot get Delphi to accept a `True` value and pass it to Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was trying to access the wrong instance of `.ContentControl.Temporary` which was compounded by my also setting the `Range.Text` value.

The following is a working version of the above example.

```
procedure TBF.SetPI;
var
  R: WordRange;
  bookmark: OleVariant;
  s: string;
  cc: ContentControl;
begin
  s := 'insert text here';
  bookmark := 'textValue';
  R := MF.WordDoc.Bookmarks.Item(bookmark).Range;
  R.Text := '';
  cc := MF.WordDoc.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, R);
  cc.SetPlaceholderText(nil, nil, s);
  cc.Range.HighlightColorIndex := wdYellow;
  cc.Temporary := true;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to assign Delphi Boolean value to WordBool.

Delphi Boolean value is 8 bit (1 byte in size). But WordBool is actually 16 bit (2 byte in size).

For more info on this check [System.WordBool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.WordBool);

Comment: This would be a better answer if you also provided a solution to the problem. :-)